# Solving linear elasticity equations for a cantilever problem

Tags: solid-mechanics

Has anyone successfully used the linear elasticity equations to model a cantilever problem?

The equation I am solving is simply:
  $$\nabla \cdot \boldsymbol{\sigma} = 0$$

subject to boundary conditions at the fixed end, free surfaces, as well as where the load is applied. I apply the load as a shear stress/traction boundary condition on the end face.

I am having no luck getting my results to match the analytical solution. I plotted the lateral displacement along the length of the beam and the shape of my curve is approximately linear, whereas the analytical solution is a cubic. When comparing max displacement in my numerical result vs the analytical result, I am off by orders of magnitude.

I've studied my code and numerics carefully and I do not see any mistakes, but I could be wrong. Is the cantilever problem able to be modeled with the equation above?

Editing this post based on the comments: In addition to the above equation, I am also using Hooke's law and the stress strain displacement relationship:

$$\boldsymbol{\sigma} = 2\mu \boldsymbol{\epsilon} + \lambda tr(\boldsymbol{\epsilon}) I$$
$$\boldsymbol{\epsilon} =0.5[\boldsymbol{\nabla u} + \boldsymbol{(\nabla u)}^T]$$

*Editing the post to include the analytical solution and dimensions.* 
The analytical solution that I am using is (http://ruina.mae.cornell.edu/Courses/ME4735-2012/Rand4770Vibrations/BeamFormulas.pdf):
$$v = \frac{Fx^2}{6EI}(3L-x)$$
Where v is the lateral displacement or the y-displacement in the link. The beam I am currently modeling has L = 10m
with a square cross section of 1m x 1m. So the moment of inertia, $I=\frac{1}{12}$ for this problem. 
I apply a force of $10^6$N at the free end, which is equivalent to a $10^6$Pa shear stress at the free end. I prescribe this as a traction boundary condition so that the boundary condition at the free surface is:
$$\sigma = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & -10^6 & 0 \\
-10^6 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

or in terms of tractions:
$$
T = \sigma n = \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
-10^6 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Attached is the result I am getting for lateral displacement for $E=2*10^{11} Pa$. [image]

Comment: Yes, people have used linear elasticity to model that problem successfully. But that equation alone does not represent linear elasticity.

Comment: To expand on the comment of @nicoguaro, the equation you show is actually three equations but with six unknowns-- the stress components. So, clearly, that equation by itself is not sufficient. Essentially all elasticity texts solve the cantilever beam problem with various loadings. See, for example, these notes: http://solidmechanics.org/Text/Chapter5_2/Chapter5_2.php#Sect5_2_4

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness. Yes I do use the additional equations, which I have now edited into my OP. The other two equations are Hooke's law and the stress strain relationship. Are there additional equations I should be considering?

Comment: What numerical method are you using?

Comment: I have tried both finite difference and finite element.

Comment: What analytical solution are you using? What are the dimensions of your beam? In principle, the equations you show above should be sufficient. I suggest you show the details of your FE solution.

Comment: I edited my original post with the analytical solution and the dimensions. I am using both finite difference and finite volume, and I will type it up later when I get on a computer. But basically I write the governing equation in terms of displacements. I discretize the 1st and 2nd order displacement gradients using a central differencing FD scheme.

Comment: A solution found using Airy stress functions also give cubic response (see https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Elasticity/Polynomial_solutions). Using Finite Elements I obtain the same results: http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/AppliedMechanics-EAFIT/SolidsPy/blob/master/examples/beam_convergence/beam_convergence.ipynb

Comment: @nicoguaro Thanks for posting this. Do you think my issue could be due to using a FD or FV discretization rather than FE?

Comment: I don't think the problem comes from the method. Maybe [this answer](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/25647/9667) can help.

Comment: Hmm. I read through the comments and answers. I discretized my rod with hex’s. I end up with 4 columns of 100 cells each. dx=0.1. dy=dz=0.5. So I don’t think it has anything to do with a lack of elements? I also ran this problem using ANSYS which matches the analytical solution.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce a simple solution? A block with uniaxial load, for example.

Comment: Yes. I have tested out my code for compression. I used the same discretization, geometry, as that of the cantilever. The only difference is I use a compression instead of a shear load at the free end. I got results for both transient&steady cases. Both match analytical results. One thing that I am unsure of regarding the cantilever is whether or not I am applying that shear load correctly. I am currently applying it as a shear load in the form of a BC at the end face. Although I don't think it would matter, but what if I applied it as a volumetric body force at the cells at the free face?

Comment: I uploaded a picture of what I am getting for the lateral displacement in the original post. The shape is wrong, the max displacement is wrong, and I don't know why there's that hook  at the free end.

Comment: I can't think of any explanation for that displacement shape except some kind of software bug. Do you want to post some kind of image of the complete, deformed position of the beam to see if we can get some clues from that?

Comment: @BillGreene I will do that some time today and tomorrow. I will also post the numerics that I implemented in solving the problem. I'm going to go through my entire code today and see if I can find anything software-wise that's causing the problem. As a side note, have you or know of any attempts at solving these equations, using finite difference, in modeling cantilever deflection?

Comment: Actually I don't have anything implemented currently that moves my mesh, so I wouldn't be able to show the beam in its deformed position. But I can plot the  the x,y,z-displacement contours and post that.

Comment: Hey all. I made a new thread with my discretization of the problem. https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/28893/discretization-used-for-steady-linear-elasticity-followup-to-previous-question

Comment: @nicoguaro, what was your governing equation in your FEM python code?

Comment: Linear elasticity: the same equation you're showing + Hooke's law, in plane stress.