# Discretization used for steady linear elasticity - followup to previous question

Tags: finite-volume, solid-mechanics

This is a follow-up of my previous scicomp question (https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/posts/28863/edit). I figured I'd start a new thread on this as the question is a bit different from my previous question.

I am solving the linear elasticity equations, using Hooke's Law and the strain-displacement relationship.

My discretization is as follows using a finite volume formulation:

$$\nabla \cdot \boldsymbol{\sigma} = \nabla \cdot (\mu \boldsymbol{\nabla u} + \mu(\boldsymbol{\nabla u})^T + \lambda\boldsymbol{I}tr(\boldsymbol{\nabla u})) = 0$$

In integral form, we have:

$$\iint_A [\mu \boldsymbol{\nabla u} + \mu(\boldsymbol{\nabla u})^T + \lambda\boldsymbol{I}tr(\boldsymbol{\nabla u})] \cdot dA = 0$$

I evaluate this surface integral using:
$$\iint_A [\mu \boldsymbol{\nabla u} + \mu(\boldsymbol{\nabla u})^T + \lambda\boldsymbol{I}tr(\boldsymbol{\nabla u})] \cdot dA = \sum\limits_{k=1}^N |A_k|n_k\cdot[\mu (\boldsymbol{\nabla u})_k + \mu(\boldsymbol{\nabla u})_k^T + \lambda\boldsymbol{I}tr(\boldsymbol{\nabla u})_k] $$

I set the above equation to $f(\boldsymbol{u})$ for simplicity. I can expand this term using a Taylor series expansion of the form:
$$f(\boldsymbol{u}) = f(0) + \frac{df}{d\boldsymbol{u}}\boldsymbol{u} = f(0) + \boldsymbol{Ju}$$

I compute the jacobian, $\boldsymbol{J}$, using a forward differencing scheme:

$$J = \frac{d\boldsymbol{f}}{d\boldsymbol{u}} = \frac{f(\boldsymbol{u}+h)-f(\boldsymbol{u})}{h}$$

So this gives us a linear system of the form:
$$\boldsymbol{Ju} = \boldsymbol{b} = -f(0)$$

Since this is a finite volume formulation, my mesh consists of cells. I compute the cell gradients using the discrete green gauss method:

$$\boldsymbol{\nabla} u = -\frac{1}{V}\sum\limits_{j=1}^N \hat{u}_jA_j\boldsymbol{n_j}$$

Where $\hat{u}=\frac{u_L+u_R}{2}$, i.e., the face displacement is obtained by averaging the neighboring cells' displacement.

I compute face gradients using a simple average and applying a correction term:
$$\nabla u_{face} = \frac{1}{2}(\nabla u_L + \nabla  u_R) - \underbrace{\hat{\boldsymbol{d_{lr}}} [\frac{1}{2}(\nabla u_L + \nabla u_R)\cdot\hat{\boldsymbol{d_{lr}}} ] + (u_L - u_R)\frac{\hat{\boldsymbol{d_{lr}}}}{|\boldsymbol{d_{lr}}|}}_{\text{Correction term}}$$

So this is the gist of my formulation.

I tried to model a cantilever problem, and it ended in a disaster (see previous question). I have tested out this formulation on the classical 1-D compression problem and was able to match analytical results.

Does anyone see anything wrong with this formulation?

Comment: Why have you linearized a system that indeed is linear? Do Lame coeff. depend on $\vec{u}$?Wouldn't it be easier with a finite element formulation? Finite element was developed for solving elasticity problems. In fact this problem leads to find the kernel $Ku=0$ of a symmetric positive definite operator $K$. Anyways... When you compute the volume average gradient of $\vec{u}$, if $\vec{n}$ is the outer normal, the minus sign is wrong (see Divergence Th.). If you are using a cartesian mesh (even more convenient if you are modeling a cantilever), there is no need to correct the gradient.

Comment: @HBR I don't have a good reason for linearizing the system other than that I was being lazy. I could form the Jacobian matrix manually, as opposed to the linearizing&using finite difference. Maybe I will try that instead, but I doubt it'll change my solution much? Lame coefficients aren't dependent on $\vec{u}$ in my code. I am developing this code to run along with another FVM code, so I would prefer to use FVM. My mistake on the minus sign (I have it correct in my code). I am currently testing my code on a cartesian mesh, but when I remove the correction term, my solution is very different.

Comment: The correction term should be 0 for a cartesian mesh, if you use a centred scheme. Is it?

Comment: @HBR  Hmmmm, I am definitely not getting 0 for my mesh. I'm currently running this on 4 columns of cells. The cells are all cubes and each face is aligned with one cartesian axis.

Comment: Why don't you remove the correction part and compute the gradient with the simple average?. Try this. With this, the numerics for this type of equation will be correct. Let's see the results.

Comment: @HBR I am overhauling my code. I'm switching over to manually forming the jacobian matrix instead of using that finite difference scheme. I am also going to use least squares to compute my cell gradients instead, and I will try a simple averaging of the neighboring gradients to get the face gradient. Did you say earlier that the correction term would be needed if the grid isn't cartesian?

Comment: @HBR Also, I did try removing the correction and computing a simple average a few days ago. The results I got changed significantly. Both of the results (using and not using the correction) did not make sense in the cantilever problem I am modeling.

Comment: The problem is already linear... I don't know why are you computing the Jacobian. Superfluous calculations are source of errors. Simple central averaging is always a good idea when elliptic PDE are solved. The correction term (I am not sure if your correction term is ok) Is necessary when the computed gradients are not aligned with the normal face vector. If you simplify the code at most and you are still obtaining nonsense results I would begin to write another code...

Comment: @HBR Terminology. I still call it the "Jacobian," because I don't know what else to call it. Basically I'm just formulating this coefficient matrix to couple the displacements together. But simple central averaging (assuming the classical FD central differencing) is not appropriate for unstructured grids? My code is built for unstructured grids. I am only using cartesian grids to debug simple problems, and in the future I will likely be working more with grids made from tets.

Comment: ok. But do not calculate the Jacobian with FD... Yes... you have to correct the gradient in unstructured grids.... but I would not trust in this correction... It seems inconsistent to me. Everything must have units of $\vec{grad}u$, and the last term... And what you need to correct is $\partial u/\partial n$ where $n$ is the normal derivative.

Comment: @HBR I will get back to you on the correction term. I am going to take a look at what I did in the code. Occasionally, when I write stuff on paper, I have some mistakes.

Comment: The $\boldsymbol{\hat{d_{lr}}}$ term is unitless. It is the unit distance vector (distance vector divided by total distance). $|\boldsymbol{d_{lr}} |$ has units of length. So the correction term is unitless.

Comment: @HBR Hey, are you sure the correction term should be zero for a cartesian mesh? I worked out some math, and I am not getting zero for a cartesian mesh.

Comment: Yes. For a uniform cartesian grid.